# Alignment in MonoDevelop

Tags: alignment, monodevelop

I switched from using Visual Studio Ultimate 2010 and I am trying to work with MonoDevelop and GTK#. I am trying to use new IDE but it seems much different than Visual Studio.
I want to develop fullscreen application that's why I must set Horizontal and Vertical alignment. In Visual Studio I can set the HorizontalAlignment property to Stretch and VerticalAlignment to Top, but MonoDevelop and Gtk# haven't this property. How can I set the same alignment in MonoDevelop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The GTK+ layout system very different to Winforms - it's based on packing widgets into containers. By default, most widgets expand to take all the space allocated to them by their parent container. For example, if you put a button directly into a window, it will fill the entire window. If you put it into a HBox/VBox, you can use the expand and fill properties to control how the box shares the available space among its child widgets, and how the widgets fill the available space.

A more exact answer would need some information about the widgets you're actually using.

Comment: I use GTKSharp, but not GTK+. For example, I need to set center alignment for Image, Table and Stretch fo Entry. How can I do it?

Comment: Example of XAML in which you can see what I want:
    <Grid>
        <Image Height="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="100,0,100,200" Stretch="Fill" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="Auto" Source="/WpfApplication6;component/Images/Koala.jpg" />
        <Grid Height="170" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="Auto">
            <Button Content="B1" Height="47" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="10,15,10,0" Width="Auto"/>
            <Button Content="B2" Height="47" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="10,80,10,0" Width="Auto" />
        </Grid>
    </Grid>

Comment: Firstly, GTK# is a C# wrapper on GTK+. So the same basic concepts apply. Your XAML is too complex for me to translate offhand, but I would, but I would suggest you look at http://developer.gnome.org/gtk-tutorial/2.90/c354.html and http://www.mono-project.com/GtkSharp:_Widget_Layout_and_Packing.